# 5 Differences between "Software Development" & "Back-end Development" that could clarify the confusion

Tags: frontend, backend

Just a question to know how the recruiters think. I know the difference between the "Front-end development" and the "Back-end Development". In a recent application process, the recruiter said that my experience was in "Software Development" but lack of "Back-end Development".

For my understanding and [techopedia](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/29568/back-end-developer), back-end development refer to everything that isn't front-end, like database and the logical part of the software/system/application, in an application online or desktop. I even think the Software development may include the front-end part.

Can you explicit say the difference between "Software Development" and "Back-end Development"? With this I can work on my CV that I can let the recruiters know if I'm talking about software development or back-end development.

Comment: _"Just a question to know how the recruiters think"_ - don't attempt to do this, because the answer is simple: they don't. Sure, there are some exceptions, but most of them do keyword matching. There's a keyword in a job description that matches a keyword on your resume? Then you're a match. If they make a distinction between common terms, **ask them** what distinction means to them, as we can only guess. Anyway, this is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: For example, I can interpret this such that you may have worked on desktop/mobile apps/web applications (as they consider that to be "software development"), but that you aren't  well-versed enough in web services/SOA, database design, IPC, availability, performance, and so on, and that they consider that to be "back-end development". But again, only they can properly explain what they mean by this, and what qualifications would make you more of a "back-end developer" than a "software developer".

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks for the information. I saw questions like this in here and I thought it could be a good question. But you made a point, probably they use keywords or they think back-end is just services/SOA, database, performance and so on and the business logical programming isn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule i would say both "Back-end Development" and "Front-End Development" are under "Software Development" Category, So basically both front-end developers and back-end developers can be called software developers.

**Front-End Developer:** Is someone who primarily works on parts of a software that end user directly interactive with, such as UI of mobile or desktop applications or websites.

**Back-End Developer:** Is someone who primarily works on parts of a software that end user does not directly interact with, such as database or core logic. Back-End is a more broader term than Front-End.

A software developer who works both on the Back-End and the Fornt-End of a software is usually called a **Full Stack Developer**, But that's not really universally used term, it's usually a term used within scope of web development.

Comment: This is your interpretation, and misses the question entirely. OP has been called too much of a "software developer" and not enough of a "back-end developer". It is unclear what they mean by this, and we can only guess.

Comment: @CodeCaster I agree with you, OP is not giving us enough information on the context where difference between "Software developer" and "Back-end developer" is begin evaluated. But i might as well answer what i know, seeing as even if he did i imagine the question would still be largely opinion based. The general difference between Front-End development and back-end development seemed like closest "not-entirely opinion based answer"